# Valor en concreto dentro de un array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, array

Tengo un dilema al imprimir una variable, verán, esta es mi consulta en SQL:

```
SELECT MONTH(fecha_del_deposito) AS mes, SUM(importe) as monto FROM pago_cliente
```

Y arroja lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cual pase a consulta en php:

```
'cantidadPagos'  => $this->Backend_model->rowCountPagos("pago_cliente"),



public function rowCountPagos($tabla)
{
   $this->db->select("MONTH(fecha_del_deposito) as mes, SUM(importe) as monto");
    $this->db->from($tabla);
    $resultados = $this->db->get();
    return $resultados->result();
}
```

Si lo imprimo con `print_r` da como resultado esto:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [mes] => 3 [monto] => 3484 ) )
```

Y necesito imprimir solo el valor de "Monto" (en este caso 3484) pero no hallo la forma adecuada, lo que hago hasta el momento es:

```
<?php echo $cantidadPagos[1]; ?>
```

Se que esta completamente mal, pero no se como hacerlo, necesito ayuda.

Gracias

Comment: `$cantidadPagos[0]->monto`

Comment: Gracias, no se por que me complique todo, pero esto es la verdad y funcional, si lo pones como respuesta oficial me gustaría calificarla para que este post este resuelto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como pudistes observar al hacer print_r a tu variable
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [mes] => 3 [monto] => 3484 ) ), esta lo que contiene
es un arreglo de 1 solo elemento y este es un objeto de tipo stdClass, como no indicastes cual era el nombre 
de la variable donde tienes asignado el resultado de tu consulta asumire que se llama $result

```
$result = [
    'cantidadPagos'  => $this->Backend_model->rowCountPagos("pago_cliente"),
]
```

Ahora si quieres imprimir solo el monto:

```
$pagos = $result['cantidadPagos'];
echo $pagos[0]->monto;

//O si no te enredas con los []
echo $result['cantidadPagos'][0]->monto;
```

Los objetos de stdClass en realidad es la manera de representar un arreglo como una instancia de una clase
, para acceder a sus llaves debes usar el operador flecha -> pues se convierten en propiedades

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy completo y buena enseñanza (Esto es lo que aprecio más).

Comment: No hay de que para eso estamos :)